# Returning or accepting 2 different value types

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

```
class apple{
    seed: number;
    color: string;
}

class orange{
    color: string;
    harvested: boolean;
}

class fruit{
    fruit1: apple;
    fruit2: orange;
    currentfruit: boolean;

    constructor{
        //something
    }

    getFruit(){
        if(!this.currentfruit){
           return this.fruit1;
        }else{
           return this.fruit2;
        }
    }

    showFruitData(){
        ???
    }
}
```

in the above case, is there a way to code the fruit class so that i can replace the ??? with:

> console.log(this.getFruit.color);

so far the closest i was able to manage is something like:

> console.log(this.getFruit().color);

which im not really satisfied with

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework assignment.

Comment: @Blazemonger actually, its not. im self-studying oop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an antipattern. Maybe you should use something like the visitor or repository pattern.

```
interface IFruit {
    color: string;
}

class Apple impliments IFruit {
    seed: number;
    color: string;
}

class Orange impliments IFruit {
    color: string;
    harvested: boolean;
}

class FruitRepository {

    repository: IFruit[];

    selectedFruitIndex: number;

    get selectedFruit() {
        return this.repository[this.selectedFruitIndex];
    }

    get showFruitData() {
        console.log(this.selectedFruit.color);
    }

}
```

A note on style. Even Crockford says that newable JavaScript objects should be PascalCase rather than camelCase. So classes, constructors and types in general should be PascalCase.